# How to reduce size of data sent via post request in python

Tags: post, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I have a SageMaker endpoint that I'm using for image segmentation, and I would like to send image data to the endpoint for segmentation. However, the files are in .tif format so before I send them off, I do a little bit of processing to convert them into a numpy ndarray. This is fine when I'm in SageMaker since I can configure the predictor to accept ndarray, but I was not able to get it to work with JSON since the data was too big to send for request (the limit is 5 MB). So, I stopped using JSON for the time being.

But now that I want to send the data via requests.post(), I'm not sure how to prepare the image data for inference. I might not be using JSON in the most efficient way. At the moment, the ndarray is 0.5 MB, but if I use json.dumps(arr), it becomes close to 10 MB, which is too big apparently. I get this error:

> ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the
> InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (413) from model and
> could not load the entire response body.

How can I prepare the data in such a way that works with requests.post()?